# Shortcutting NuGet locally

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, nuget, versioning

We have two Visual Studio solutions, F and C. F is a framework. C is a client that uses dll:s produced by F.

We don't want to create a single solution containing both F and C. Rather, we want F to produce a NuGet package that is consumed by C.

Our current solution is to manually run a script that copies the DLL:s produced by F into a specific folder in C. The copied DLL:s are referenced as files by C. The binary DLL files are checked in to version control. It is not elegant, but it is very fast. The copy takes a fraction of a second.

Our experience is that NuGet becomes a hindrance when doing development locally of both F and C. Let's say a developer is doing work on the interface of F and how C uses it. This developer then has to work in both F and C, switching back and forth frequently.

In that scenario copying DLL:s each time F is updated is very fast. If we introduce NuGet, then the process is considerably slowed down:

Each time F is modified it needs to be built on TeamCity to produce a proper NuGet package. C must then do a NuGet update on all projects using the NuGet package to get the new version. Both waiting for a TeamCity build and updating all the references is slow. The first takes mintues, the second can also take in the order of a minute.

Alternatively, F could be compiled locally to produce a NuGet to a local NuGet repository. This is faster than a TeamCity build. But the NuGet references in C still need to be updated, which is still slow. And the package.config of C will now contain a reference to a NuGet version that does not exist on the central NuGet repository, so this is error prone. Also, we have to configure C to read from the local repository, something that should not be checked in. The local repository has to be cleaned up when you are done with the local devolopment.

What would be better is if we could easily circumvent NuGet locally, so that we did not have to update the NuGet references at every change in F. Is there any smart way of doing this? Our scenario seems like a standard requirement to me. I've seen the problem in two major projects now.

We've tried to use [Reference Paths in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8y13ka7c%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), hoping that we could override the path to the binaries that way (and then still use a copy script to bring over the DLL:s to a separate folder). But the HintPath seems to take precedence over the Reference Path.

Comment: Sounds like you have a lot of coupling between the projects, so you'd either need to stop messing around with the interface so often, to the point of considering it a separate product, or move both projects into the same solution

Comment: @RowlandShaw In an ideal world, I agree. But this is in a corporate environment, so restructuring the way you suggest is not really an option.

Comment: Having multiple framework projects in multiple product solutions works for our corporate environment (along with continuous integration, etc.)

Comment: @RowlandShaw I'm glad things work for you, but I do not have the power to change our environment at that level.

Comment: @KlasMellbourn - I agree with Rowland. You're "fighting stupid" instead of "making awesome" by not getting the code boundaries right. If a developer has to make changes to F and C often, then they are likely actually coupled, by definition.

Comment: @KlasMellbourn why is your "corporate environment " dictating your solution structure?

Comment: @andy One aspect is that it is a large base of legacy code.